# Activate function on a specific element of a select JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I would make sure that the items in select from activating the specific features I'll explain. 
I have this select:

```
<select id='selection'> <!-->this is for the class<!-->
   <option>4B</option>
   <option>5B</option>
</select>

<select id='secondSelection'> <!-->this is for the data to be loaded<!-->
</select>
```

if I select 4B must load all pupils corresponding to that class, pupils are in the array 4B. 
if instead go to select 5B must be able to load in the other select the contents of the 5B. The user can also decide to select both classes.

EXAMPLE:

4B [selected in selection] => Mario, Luigi, John are now loaded in secondSelection

similarly for all values ​​have to be able to do the same thing by enabling multiple.
I have already made a similar code in the past, but here the situation is a bit 'different, I would like the help of an expert. PEACE!

Comment: need jQuery solution?

Comment: no, i use pure javascript no jquery

Comment: Please post what you have tried and explain specifically where you are stuck. Questions about connected selects have been asked many times already.

Comment: You have to listen `change` event on the select

Comment: have a look at --> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
var b4 = ["Mario", "Luigi", "John"],
    b5 = ["Some", "Other", "Names"],
    elem = document.getElementById('selection');
elem.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('secondSelection').innerHTML = this[elem.options[this.selectedIndex].text == "4B" ? "b4" : "b5 "].map(function (x) {
        return "<option>" + x "</option>";
    }).join();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">
```

`<script>
function myFunction(){
}
</script>`

it will also work